# Finding the difference between two sets of data from the same table

Tags: sql, h2

My data looks like:

```
run | line | checksum | group
-----------------------------
 1  |   3  |  123     |  1
 1  |   7  |  123     |  1
 1  |   4  |  123     |  2
 1  |   5  |  124     |  2
 2  |   3  |  123     |  1
 2  |   7  |  123     |  1
 2  |   4  |  124     |  2
 2  |   4  |  124     |  2
```

and I need a query that returns me the new entries in run 2

```
run | line | checksum | group
-----------------------------
 2  |   4  |  124     |  2
 2  |   4  |  124     |  2
```

I tried several things, but I never got to a satisfying answer.
In this case I'm using H2, but of course I'm interested in a general explanation that would help me to wrap my head around the concept.

**EDIT:**
OK, it's my first post here so please forgive if I didn't state the question precisely enough.

Basically given two run values (r1, r2, with r2 > r1) I want to determine which rows having row = r2 have a different line, checksum or group from any row where row = r1.

Comment: question makes no sense as it stands...

Comment: How do you determine that an entry is new?

Comment: what do you mean by the new entries in run 2 ? I see no datastamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourtable
where run = 2 and checksum = (select max(checksum) 
                              from yourtable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your last run will have the higher run value than others, below SQL will help

```
select * from table1 t1
where t1.run in
(select max(t2.run) table1 t2)
```

**Update:**

Above SQL may not give you the right rows because your requirement is not so clear. But the overall idea is to fetch the rows based on the latest run parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT line, checksum, group 
  FROM TableX
  WHERE run = 2 

EXCEPT

SELECT line, checksum, group 
  FROM TableX
  WHERE run = 1
```

or (with slightly different result):

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableX x
  WHERE run = 2
    AND NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM TableX x2
          WHERE run = 1
            AND x2.line = x.line
            AND x2.checksum = x.checksum
            AND x2.group = x.group 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach:

```
select min(run) run, line, checksum, group
from mytable
where run in (1,2)
group by line, checksum, group
having count(*)=1 and min(run)=2
```

Incidentally, I assume that the "group" column in your table isn't actually called group - this is a reserved word in SQL and would need to be enclosed in double quotes (or backticks or square brackets, depending on which RDBMS you are using).